# Check if date field in database is expired in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

i've the this token table

```
-------------------------------------------------
user_id   | time           | token
-------------------------------------------------
user1     | 2014-10-01     | hsgdhsdgjsggs34hgxsd
user2     | 2014-09-18     | sghsgsdgsj454gfhdfg4
user3     | 2014-12-25     | dfhjdfhjdgee7722dhdd
```

The time field is populate with php function time() and represent the insert time/date;

So in my application i've to check if the token field is valid or not, it expires after 6 month. How to check it?

i've used this approach

```
function checkToken($token, PDO $pdo) { 
    if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT time FROM Token WHERE token = ? AND time + INTERVAL 180 DAY > NOW()")) {
        $stmt->execute(array($token));
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to check the time in SQL. You clearly know which row you're interested in, so just get the whole row and do any processing of that data in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `INTERVAL 6 MONTH` but you also need the DAY_ADD() function, the query would be something like this (haven't tested it, there may be an error in there):

```
SELECT time FROM Token WHERE token = ? AND DAY_ADD(time, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) > NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Only use SQL when it's efficient or necessary

It's my personal preference to keep SQL commands as simple as possible. In your case I would see no need to perform the date check in SQL, I would simply get the row and perform the date check in PHP, like this:

```
function hasTokenExpired(PDO $pdo,$token) 
{ 
  // set the days till the token expires
  $daysTillExpire = 180;
  // get the row with the token
  if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Token WHERE token = ?')) 
  {
    $stmt->execute(array($token));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(FETCH_ASSOC);
    // if we got the row see it the token has expired
    if (isset($row)) return ($row['time'] < time()-$daysTillExpire*24*60*60);
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

(not debugged!). Most of the time I would need a row, like this one, for multiple things, so I'll wrap it into a class, read it once and use the data multiple times. This lowers the load on the database significantly.